# How to remove white space around HighChart

Tags: highcharts

I have got problem. Around my 3D Pie Highchart, there is white space, but i have got Background, set by HTML, and i want to see it. So please how do I remove it?

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-pie/) example and explain more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `backgroundColor: 'transparent',`

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 45,
            beta: 0
        },
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
...
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6JnST/)

Answer (score 0):

set margin to 0

`margin: [0,0,0,0]`

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WbC34/) link for that

I hope this is the space you are looking to remove.